# disable 'changeHash' option on anchor-triggered page change

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

In my JQM application, I have two pages who navigate between themselves via HTML anchors, but I don't want them to change the hash (and update the history thread) when they are clicked. This is because they both have a back button that should exit either of the two pages to return to the original page that called either of these pages.

With $.changePage, you can set the option for the page change to change the has or not, is there a way to assign it to anchors individually (such as with a data attribute) for it to take effect only for when those specific anchors are triggered?

Comment: `changeHash:false` will only hide hash in URL bar but still history is updated.

Comment: Is there a way to stop the history from being updated?

Comment: There is a way to modify `$.mobile.urlHistroy`.